# dmesg shows usb, not fdisk

Tags: fedora, usb

I am trying to connect my android phone that has a broken screen, trying to retrieve data. It shows up in dmesg,lsusb but not on fdisk or gparted

dmesg============

```
[ 2583.040729] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 2583.167768] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=22d9, idProduct=2769, bcdDevice= 2.23
[ 2583.167784] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2583.167791] usb 1-1: Product: DN2101
[ 2583.167796] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: OnePlus
[ 2583.167801] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: JFHQAxxxxxxxxxx
```

lsusb============

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5691 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 22d9:2769 OPPO Electronics Corp. DN2101
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

sudo fdisk -l============

```
Disk /dev/sda: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: Micron 1100 SATA
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D98F7C19-D647-4D38-ACCA-DD6CACAC88E8

Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    1026047   1024000   500M EFI System
/dev/sda2     1026048    1288191    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     1288192  208869375 207581184    99G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4   208869376  242423807  33554432    16G Linux swap
/dev/sda5   242423808  247500799   5076992   2.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6   247502848  516526079 269023232 128.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda7   516526080  575833539  59307460  28.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda8   575834112  784371711 208537600  99.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda9   784373760 1000002927 215629168 102.8G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda10 1000003584 1000212479    208896   102M Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/zram0: 8 GiB, 8589934592 bytes, 2097152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/loop0: 116.76 MiB, 122433536 bytes, 239128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 55.61 MiB, 58310656 bytes, 113888 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 55.56 MiB, 58261504 bytes, 113792 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 49.84 MiB, 52260864 bytes, 102072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: the phone is not recognised as a "mass storage device" - so it won't show up as one

Comment: As the phone is not recognized as a mass storage device, you should probably investigate `adb` as the next step. You probably want to visit android.stackexchane.com